# My program throws no exception, but it behaves strangely

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I don't understand why this program doesn't work.
The goal is to display a new random value on the dice when you press space. It is not an exception to throw, but an interesting thing happens when we run.
The program first creates the square, the dots, and then defines a function for each roll, which it combines in the "dob" function.
In an infinite loop, this function is called when "space" is pressed and a random number is continuously generated.

```py
from random import *
from tkinter import *
ablak = Tk ()
ablak.title ('Dobókocka')
v = Canvas (ablak, width=500, height=500, bg='orange')
v.pack ()
a = 'white'
v.create_rectangle (200, 200, 300, 300,fill='red')
v.create_text (250, 20, text='Nyomd meg a \'space\'-t!')
egy =v.create_oval (240, 240, 260, 260, outline=a, fill=a, state=NORMAL)
kettőa = v.create_oval (220, 220, 240, 240, outline=a, fill=a,state=HIDDEN)
kettőb = v.create_oval (280, 280, 260, 260, outline=a,fill=a, state=HIDDEN)
négyb = v.create_oval (280, 220, 260, 240, outline=a, fill=a, state=HIDDEN)
négyc = v.create_oval (220, 280, 240, 260, outline=a, fill=a, state=HIDDEN)
hatc = v.create_oval (220, 240, 240, 260, outline=a, fill=a, state=HIDDEN)
hatd = v.create_oval (280, 260, 260, 240, outline=a, fill=a, state=HIDDEN)
ablak.update ()
def egyes ():
    v.itemconfig (egy, state=NORMAL)
def kettes ():
    v.itemconfig (kettőa, state=NORMAL)
    v.itemconfig (kettőb, state=NORMAL)
def hármas ():
    kettes ()
    egyes ()
def négyes ():
    kettes ()
    v.itemconfig (négyb, state=NORMAL)
    v.itemconfig (négyc, state=NORMAL)
def ötös ():
    négyes ()
    egyes ()
def hatos ():
    négyes ()
    v.itemconfig (hatc, state=NORMAL)
    v.itemconfig (hatd, state=NORMAL)
def dob ():
    v.itemconfig (egy, state=HIDDEN)
    v.itemconfig (kettőa, state=HIDDEN)
    v.itemconfig (kettőb, state=HIDDEN)
    v.itemconfig (négyb, state=HIDDEN)
    v.itemconfig (négyc, state=HIDDEN)
    v.itemconfig (hatc, state=HIDDEN)
    v.itemconfig (hatd, state=HIDDEN)
    if dobás == 1:
        egyes ()
    elif dobás == 2:
        kettes ()
    elif dobás == 3:
        hármas ()
    elif dobás == 4:
        négyes ()
    elif dobás == 5:
        ötös ()
    else:
        hatos ()
    ablak.update ()
def gomb ():
        dob ()
while True:
    dobás = randint (1, 6)
    v.bind_all ('<space>', dob ())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run your code, however you have given enough information to me to venture an answer.

Your code does not include `ablak.mainloop()`, so assuming you haven't included that then the following code may help.

If you replace the infinite loop `while True` and related code with the following code it should work.

```py
def gomb ():
    global dobás
    dobás = randint(1, 6)
    dob()

ablak.bind('<space>', gomb)
ablak.mainloop()
```

This should at least get you out of your infinite loop problem.

Comment: It really solves the problem of the infinite loop, but instead of ```window.bind ('<space>', button)``` instead of  ```window.bind ('<space>', button ())```  is correct, otherwise it will run on error . While the program is running, a random value is displayed on the dice, but pressing "space" is in vain.
Thanks for your reply.